# How to sort the words by their frequency

Tags: java, sorting, word-frequency

I take an input text file, convert it to an array, sort the array, and then get the frequencies of each word. I can't figure out how to sort them according to their frequencies, from highest to lowest, without importing lots of things (which is what I am trying to do):

```
//find frequencies
    int count = 0;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s:words){
        if(!list.contains(s)){
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++){
            if(list.get(i).equals(words[j])){
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(list.get(i) + "\t" + count);
        count=0;
    }
```

This returns the words with their frequencies in an unsorted order, for example:

```
the 3
with 7
he 8
```

etc.

I want this to be sorted like:

```
he 8
with 7
the 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it like so,

```
private static class Tuple implements Comparable<Tuple> {
    private int count;
    private String word;

    public Tuple(int count, String word) {
        this.count = count;
        this.word = word;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tuple o) {
        return new Integer(this.count).compareTo(o.count);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return word + " " + count;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = { "the", "he", "he", "he", "he", "he", "he", "he",
            "he", "the", "the", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with",
            "with", "with" };
    // find frequencies
    Arrays.sort(words);
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String s : words) {
        if (map.containsKey(s)) {
            map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(s, 1);
        }
    }
    List<Tuple> al = new ArrayList<Tuple>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        al.add(new Tuple(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey()));
    }
    Collections.sort(al);
    System.out.println(al);
}
```

Output is,

```
[the 3, with 7, he 8]
```

Comment: I like how this is sorting the frequencies, but I need the output to be in the descending order -  from biggest to lowest, and as a table like in my code.

Comment: @nanachan Then change compareTo to `return new Integer(o.count).compareTo(this.count);` and the toString method should use a `\t`.

Comment: if I set toString to be with a \t it still returns an array like 
`[he   8,with     7,the    3]`

Comment: @nanachan Remove `System.out.println(al);` and do `for (Tuple t : al) System.out.println(t);`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a small helper class:

```
class WordFreq implements Comparable<WordFreq> {
   final String word;
   int freq;
   @Override public int compareTo(WordFreq that) {
     return Integer.compare(this.freq, that.freq);
   }
}
```

Build an array of instances of this class, one for each word, then sort the array using `Arrays.sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an object of type `Word` that holds the word's `String` value and its frequency.

Then you can implement `compareTo` or use a `Comparator` and call `Collections.sort()` on your list of type `Word`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<String, Integer>` instead to store both your `String` as key and the frequency as value, with initial value of 1. If the word already exists, just update the value by increasing it by 1. Then, convert this map into a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` (or a [Guava `Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)) and use the `Integer` values as keys and the `String` keys to store them as values.