# Sorting a tuple(int, string) and save the string values in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, tuples

I am using this code to sort pairs of words and integer, sorting the pairs by the integers (descending order)

After I sort the tuple, how can I save only the string values in a String [] array?

I found the code here, I could not comment on the same page since I am new here. (@ Elliott Frisch)

[How to sort the words by their frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515889/how-to-sort-the-words-by-their-frequency)

```
 public Tuple(int count, String word) {
    this.count = count;
    this.word = word;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Tuple o) {
    return new Integer(this.count).compareTo(o.count);
}
public String toString() {
    return word + " " + count;
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] words = { "the", "he", "he", "he", "he", "he", "he", "he",
        "he", "the", "the", "with", "with", "with", "with", "with",
        "with", "with" };
// find frequencies
Arrays.sort(words);
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String s : words) {
    if (map.containsKey(s)) {
        map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(s, 1);
    }
}
List<Tuple> al = new ArrayList<Tuple>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    al.add(new Tuple(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey()));
}
Collections.sort(al);
System.out.println(al);
```

}

Comment: *FYI:* `new Integer(this.count).compareTo(o.count)` should be `Integer.compare(this.count, o.count)`

Comment: Are you truly asking how to create a `String[]`, then iterate the `al` list to assign the values to the array? Have you tried a simple `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has to be necessarily array here you go:

```
        Collections.sort(al);
        String[] wordsResult = new String[al.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Tuple tuple : al) {
            wordsResult[i++] = tuple.word;
        }
        Stream.of(wordsResult).forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println(al);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Stream-API to sort this ArrayList

```
 Object[] arr = al.stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Tuple::getCount).reversed())//sort counts as per count
.map(Tuple::getWord) //mapping to each count to word
.toArray(); //collect all words to array
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

You can also collect these words to `List<String>`

```
List<String> arr =al.stream() 
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Tuple::getCount).reversed())//sort counts as per count
.map(Tuple::getWord) //mapping to each count to word
.collect(Collectors.toList())//Collect to List
```